# How to compare two data frames and use conditional format

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, python-2.6

**Hi folks.**

I want to format unique cells after comparing two dataframe tables. in otherwords when two tables have the same data, i want the (Conditional formatting) unique cells to be highlighted. ** I'm Using pandas 16.2**

**Compare each df columns data is the same df1**

```
person_compare = df['A'].isin(df1['A'])
location_compare = df['B'].isin(df1['B'])
details_compare = df['C'].isin(df1['C'])
```

Comment: Pandas does not highlight cells. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that highlighting is possible but this code helps you compare column A and B and find those values that are unique:

```
df["unique values"] = df["A"][~df["A"].isin(df["B"])].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: is it possible to use openpyxl instead?

Comment: I dont know, I am not familiar with openpyxl. But you might want to check out their docs to see if it fits your purpose: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html